# How can I get this Java generics code to work properly?

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes in my Java project:

```
public abstract class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {

      private Comparable<T> data[];
      private int numberOfElements;

      public Heap( int size ) {

           //I am also not sure if this cast will work or is best practice

           data = (Comparable<T>[]) new Comparable<?>[ size + 1 ];

           numberOfElements = 0;
      }

      public void incrementNumberOfElements() { numberOfElements++; }

      public int getNumberOfElements() { return numberOfElements; }

      public Comparable<T>[] getData() { return data; }

      public abstract void insert( Comparable<T> element );
}

class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Heap<T> {

     public MinHeap( int size ) { super(size); }

     public void insert( Comparable<T> element ) {

           incrementNumberOfElements();

           Comparable<T> data[] = getData();

           int current = getNumberOfElements();

           data[ current ] = element;


         //The error is with compareTo()
          while ( current / 2 >= 1 && data[ current ].compareTo( data[ current / 2 ] ) < 0 ) {

                      //code

          }
     }

 }
```

I am getting the following compile time error with the compareTo() method: `The method compareTo(T) in the type Comparable<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable<T>)`. If I cast the data such as this: `data[ current ].compareTo( (T) data[ current / 2 ] )` then the error goes away but there is a warning.

My question is this: Is adding the cast  `data[ current ].compareTo( (T) data[ current / 2 ] )` the best way to go about making this work? If not, what are some suggestions to make this better? My goal is to create a Heap that can be used with any class that implements the Comparable interface.

I am not too familiar with using generics, so any *helpful* suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public void insert( T element )` - because you want to insert element of type T and above (`class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<T>>`) is specified that T must be extending Comparable.
I have changed your code to use array list instead of Array, not sure if you have a requirement to use arrays.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private List<T> data;
private int numberOfElements;

public Heap( int size ) {

    //I am also not sure if this cast will work or is best practice

    data = new ArrayList<T>(size + 1 );

    numberOfElements = 0;
}

public void incrementNumberOfElements() { numberOfElements++; }
public int getNumberOfElements() { return numberOfElements; }
public List<T> getData() { return data; }
public abstract void insert( T element );
}

class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Heap<T> {

public MinHeap( int size ) { super(size); }
public void insert( T element ) {

    incrementNumberOfElements();
    List<T> data = getData();
    int current = getNumberOfElements();
    data.set(current, element);

    //The error is with compareTo()
    while ( current / 2 >= 1 && data.get(current).compareTo( data.get(current / 2) ) < 0 ) {

        //code

    }
}

}
```

Comment: The realization I have come to is that generics and arrays to do not mix well. I went with the array list implementation just as you suggested. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` should be `T[]` instead of `Comparable<T>[]`. That makes the most sense. Also, if it's `T[]`, then when you get an element out it is `T`, which can compare to itself. But if it's `Comparable<T>`, that does not guarantee that it can compare to itself.

But you also cannot have a method `T[] getData()`. 1) The `data` variable is an internal implementation detail and you should not let the outside have a reference to it. And 2) there is no way you can create an array of a certain component type without knowing that component type at runtime, which you don't in this class.